# htaccess content negotiation not working on LiteSpeed server

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, litespeed

We have code in our htaccess that presents a different web template for mobile users like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "Mobile"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!_mob.php"
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$    /$1_mob.php [L,QSA]
```

So a file *foo.php* would be internally rewritten to *foo_mob.php* if the condition evaluates to true.
Now we have additional a 'pretty-url' directive that rewrites the descriptive category and product page names to the internal format based on query strings like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category1\.htm
RewriteRule ^.*$  /index.php?cPath=1 [L,QSA]
```

In combination with the above this should then display the template *index_mob.php* to the user on a mobile device. This has been working fine for many years with Apache server, but is not working anymore after we moved to a LiteSpeed server now. The mobile template is displayed for requests with an explicit .php extension, but not those that have gone through the rewrite to *index.php* first (that includes also the root / that is rewritten to *index.php* by default)

Any help to solve the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please post your complete htaccess file in your question, along with information like: FROM which url TO which url you want to rewrite/redirect? Thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The above details should be enough. I have narrowed it down to this through extensive tests. The rest of the htaccess file has no effect on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use both above .htaccess rules in Combination while using Litespeed, The problem is the `L` tag being in the `.htaccess` twice.

[L] tag stands for Last, and has different meanings in Apache and Litespeed.

The ruleset after an [L] flag may still be processed by Apache on a subsequent iteration, but that is not true with Litespeed and most other contexts.

Additional information and Official Documentation is [here](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:troubleshooting:rewrite_difference_on_l_flag_between_lsws_and_apache).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have been told this already, but it is not true (at least not for the server where I am having these problems). If I have the rules *RewriteRule ^page1.php*  /page2.php [L]* and *RewriteRule ^page2.php*    /page3.php [L]* on top of each other I am getting *page3.php* when requesting *page1.php*, so it is parsing the first rewrite again. In any case, it doesn't make a difference removing all [L] flags. The problem remains.